# What possible reasons can cause mysql queue limit reach issue in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, queue, restify

I have a nodeJs application which receives requests ranging from 0-3000 requests per minute(irregular, no pattern). About 80%-90% of the requests cause mysql insert or update operations.

Node version - 4.2.2
Mysql version - 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
the nodejs framework used is Restify

I am getting the connections from a mysql connection pool of size 20.

I time to time(sporadic) see "mysql queue limit reached" issue. What can possibly cause this issue?(apart from the following causes)

1. Connections are not closed properly
2. Queue size is not sufficient(How can I determine the optimal queue size?)
3. Problem with nodejs or mysql versions (what versions could be used to solve this?)
4. Problem in mysql queries(What possible issues could be there in queries related to this issue?)
5. Probelm with the nodejs framework used(Would using expressJs solve this?)

**Edit1**
Here is a frame how I have queried the database

```
connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    } else {
        let args = [param1, param2];
        let query = "SELECT...";

        conn.query(query, args, function (err, rows) {
            conn.release();
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            } else {
                return callback(null, rows);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Edit2**
Here is the mysql configuration I have as of now. I have not much of an idea about these values. Are they fine?

```
{
    "connectionLimit": 10,
    "acquireTimeout": 60000,
    "host": "*****",
    "port": "3306",
    "user": "*****",
    "password": "****",
    "database": "*****",
    "charset": "UTF8_GENERAL_CI",
    "debug": false,
    "waitForConnections" : true,
    "queueLimit" : 15000
}
```

Comment: Which framework are you using to connect to mysql in node? Having too many connections should give you another error, so likely not the problem. queue size seems to be a construct of your nodejs framework for connecting to mysql, if im not mistaking, so the issue might be here. I highly doubt node or mysql is the reason for this problem.

Comment: I am using the mysql nodejs driver for connecting the db. It seemed to be the most stable and popular driver
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: And yes, queue size is a constructorof the driver, done via the nodejs code

Comment: Could you include some of your code here? like the initial configuration of the driver and the functions where the errors might occur?

Comment: Edited the post as you suggested

Comment: Dodangode your code seems correct, so based on these examples I would not guess you have a problem. Could you try setting debug: true and, unless sensitive, post some of your log around the time you have the problem as well? If I recall correctly, the debug log will reveal information regarding queues. Basically it seems that you are getting 15000+ requests in addition to the 10 already being served at a single given time when you get the error. I assume this is the backend of a website: Are you requesting multiple sql queries for each request? for example 1 webpage requires 2+ queries

Comment: Yes you are correct, this is a backend of a web site. then I guess this error is caused by resource limitations in the server and queries being not optimal. I will first optimize the queries and then try to figure out the optimal values to be used as the mysql server variables. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good idea from performance perspective to use so called "*connection pooling*".

Connection pooling is mechanism to maintain cache of database connection so that connection can be reused after releasing it. In `Node.js` MySQL pooling can be used directly to handle multiple connection **and more important - reuse the connection**. For example:

```
var express   =    require("express");
var mysql     =    require('mysql');
var app       =    express();

var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : '***',
    password : '***',
    database : 'database_name',
    debug    :  false
});

function db_connect(req,res) {       
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if (err) {
          res.json({"code" : "error", "status" : "Error in database connection."});
          return;
        }    
        console.log('Connection ID: ' + connection.threadId);
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM `table1`",function(err,rows){
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
                res.json(rows);
            }          
        });    
        connection.on('error', function(err) {      
              res.json({"code" : "error", "status" : "Error in database connection."});
        return;    
        });
  });
}    
app.get("/",function(req,res){
        db_connect(req,res);
}); 
//Run on port 3000
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: How can I determine the value to be used for the connectionLimit variable. FYI, the max_connections system variable is set to 151(I think it's the default value). I have no idea even what the value for the max_connections system variable should be. Can u explain a bit about it?

Comment: It is hard to say - it depends on your server load. In general values between 100 and 500 for connections will be sufficient for low to moderate server load from my experience.

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda This limit is something you have to continuously consitter. If you have a lot of slow queries and high traffic, you need more connections available. if you only have fast queries, you can be safe with fewer. Now, why don't you just allow a gazillion connections? Well, you want it to be as close to your actual limit s possible, so it can trigger if something is wrong. For example, if connections are not closing correctly, queries are taking insanely long to complete, etc. These are cases where you need to investigate further, and you wont easily notice with a high limit.